# Constructor of Spring Session Scope Bean is invoked during Startup and Twice

Tags: spring, session, proxy, aop

Based on Spring [manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying),

> The constructor of your proxied object will be called **twice**. This is a
>   natural consequence of the CGLIB proxy model whereby a subclass is
>   generated for each proxied object. For each proxied instance, two
>   objects are created: the actual proxied object and an instance of the
>   subclass that implements the advice.

I have a class which is session scope. I observed the constructor is called **first time during application startup**, even there is no HTTPSession. The second time is during a HTTPSession is created. How could I delay the bean instantiation with `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` only if there is a session? I have tried annotated with `@Lazy` but has no effect.

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class WorkspaceImpl implements Workspace, Serializable {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you take the side effect of CGLIB proxy, or change to `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACE` by making the target class to implement an interface (if you own the class), which uses JDK dynamic proxy. See the difference between JDK dynamic proxy and CGLib at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664208/418439