# Spring Boot @Autowired with Kotlin in @Service is always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

Currently I try to rewrite my Java Spring Boot Application with Kotlin. I encountered a problem that in all of my classes which are annotated with `@Service` the dependency injection is not working correctly (all instances are `null`). Here is an example:

```
@Service
@Transactional
open class UserServiceController @Autowired constructor(val dsl: DSLContext, val teamService: TeamService) {
  //dsl and teamService are null in all methods
}
```

Doing the same in Java works without any problems:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceController
{
    private DSLContext dsl;
    private TeamService teamService;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceController(DSLContext dsl,
                             TeamService teamService)
    {
        this.dsl = dsl;
        this.teamService = teamService;
    }
```

If I annotate the component with `@Component` in Kotlin everything works fine:

```
@Component
open class UserServiceController @Autowired constructor(val dsl: DSLContext, val teamService: TeamService) {
  //dsl and teamService are injected properly
}
```

Google provided many different approaches for Kotlin and `@Autowired` which I tried but all resulted in the same `NullPointerException`
I would like to know what the difference between Kotlin and Java is and how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing val to var?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null Pointer Exception In Spring Proxy Class and Kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431817/null-pointer-exception-in-spring-proxy-class-and-kotlin)

Comment: Yes I already tried both.

Comment: Try adding  @Autowired  before val and remove construtor. This works for me

Comment: Maybe you are using `GenericApplicationContext` instead of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

Answer (score 22):

I just bumped into exactly same issue - injection worked well, but after adding @Transactional annotation all the autowired fields are null.

My code:

```
@Service
@Transactional  
open class MyDAO(val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate) {

   fun update(sql: String): Int {
       return jdbcTemplate.update(sql)
   }

}
```

The problem here is that the methods are final by default in Kotlin, so Spring is unable to create proxy for the class:

```
 o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy: Unable to proxy method [public final int org.mycompany.MyDAO.update(...
```

"Opening" the method fixes the issue:

Fixed code:

```
@Service
@Transactional  
open class MyDAO(val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate) {

   open fun update(sql: String): Int {
       return jdbcTemplate.update(sql)
   }

}
```

Comment: Kotlin has a build plugin to open these classes: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Comment: Awsome!! it also fix bean injection issue!

Comment: Add "open" before "fun" is really help.
Thanks mate.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem working with Kotlin but the null instance was a JpaRepository. When I added the `@Transactional` annotation to a method inside a service, I got a message saying `Methods annotated with '@Transactional' must be overridable` so I went ahead and marked both, the class and the method as `open`. Easy, right?! Well, not quite.

Although this compiles, I got the required repository as null at execution time. I was able to solve the problem in two ways:

1. Mark the class and **ALL of its methods** as `open`:

```
open class FooService(private val barRepository: BarRepository) {
    open fun aMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }

    @Transactional
    open fun aTransactionalMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works but having all the methods in a class marked with `open` might look a bit odd, so I tried something else.

2. Declare an interface:

```
interface IFooService {
    fun aMethod(): Bar

    fun aTransactionalMethod(): Bar
}

open class FooService(private val barRepository: BarRepository) : IFooService {
    override fun aMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }

    @Transactional
    override fun aTransactionalMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you can still use the annotation since all the methods will be overridable and you won't need to use `open` everywhere.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: I dont understand.. Tried the exact same approach - but as soon as i add OPEN class - it fks up the dep. injection. val repository: Foo is NULL. And when i remove Open it doesnt let me apply transactional. SO Freaking angry

Answer (score 4):

Which Spring Boot version do you use? Since 1.4 Spring Boot is based on Spring Framework 4.3 and since then you should be able to use constructor injection without any `@Autowired` annotation at all. Have you tried that?

It would look like this and works for me:

```
@Service
class UserServiceController(val dsl: DSLContext, val teamService: TeamService) {

  // your class members

}
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do this without getting a `No default constructor found` and also by not making the properties null-able? ***(FYI Some of my parameters are repositories)***

Comment: I already solved my problem. For those who are getting the `No default constructor` or the @Autowired is already found. Make sure that your constructor doesn't have default values.