# Spring proxy default impl

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, cglib

I think I have a good idea of how spring uses proxy concept with `@Transactional` annotation but I can't find anything about "default" implementation. Basically what I'm looking for is the code which wraps the invocation of original method (method from wrapped object).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a default implementation because it all depends on the class implementing the method where you add the `@Transactional` annotation to.
If that class inherits from an interface then [JDK Dynamic Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) will be used.
If not, then an external library called CGLIB will be used to create the proxy.
Dynamic proxy will create a proxy that implements all interfaces your target class also implements while CGLIB will create a proxy that extends your target class.

Also make sure to read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664182/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-dynamic-proxy-and-cglib) concerning the difference between Dynamic Proxy and CGLIB proxy as it contains valuable information as well.